# JSON.stringify set root element

Tags: javascript, json

I want to convert my object into a JSON String where the root element should be the name of my object.

```
var data = {
  name: 'qwertz',
  age: 23,
  skills: [
    'html', 'css'            
  ]
}

var json = JSON.stringify(data);
```

The output is:

```
{"name":"qwertz","age":23,"skills":["html","css"]}
```

But I want this:

```
{"data":{"name":"qwertz","age":23,"skills":["html","css"]}}
```

Can someone give me a hint how to reach this? Thanks you :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As simple as that:

```
var json = JSON.stringify({ data: data });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
JSON.stringify({'data':data})
```